# R rename columns (hlookup)

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
data <- data.frame(c=1:5, ID=0,a=2,b=5:9)
naming <- data.frame(short=c("a","b","c", "d", "e"), long=c("aa","bb","cc", "dd", "ee"))
```

I would like to rename the columns in data frame `data` from `c,ID,b,a` to `cc,ID,bb,aa`

I tried:

```
colnames(data) <- naming[match(naming$short, colnames(data)),2]
```

but this does not work, as both vectors are not of the same length, further, I would like to keep the column names in `data`, that are not in `naming`.

Any suggestions? Basically its `hlookup` function from Excel, but due to large data files I cannot do this in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `dplyr` 's `rename_at` and passing an anonymous functions seems to fit your purposes

```
require(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(c=1:5, ID=0,a=2,b=5:9)

data 
#   c ID a b
# 1 1  0 2 5
# 2 2  0 2 6
# 3 3  0 2 7
# 4 4  0 2 8
# 5 5  0 2 9

cols_iwant_to_rename <- c("a","b","c")



data <- 
data %>% rename_at(cols_iwant_to_rename , function(x) paste0(x, x)) 

data 

#    cc ID aa bb
# 1  1  0  2  5
# 2  2  0  2  6
# 3  3  0  2  7
# 4  4  0  2  8
# 5  5  0  2  9
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```r
matches <- match(names(data), naming$short)
matches
# [1]  3 NA  1  2
ifelse(is.na(matches), names(data), naming$long[matches])
# [1] "cc" "ID" "aa" "bb"
names(data) <- ifelse(is.na(matches), names(data), naming$long[matches])
data
#   cc ID aa bb
# 1  1  0  2  5
# 2  2  0  2  6
# 3  3  0  2  7
# 4  4  0  2  8
# 5  5  0  2  9
```